# ALSA - snd_pcm_writei - not using all frames

Tags: c

My playback stops after about 20 seconds, when I set non-blocking mode. I first read a file complete to RAM, the buffer is called "buffer_alsa", there are bframes frames in it (here 6894888). Played in blocking mode it works. Played with non-blocking mode it stops after 1048576 frames. I looped it, but no change. Any idea?

```
snd_pcm_open(&handle, carddevice, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK,SND_PCM_NONBLOCK)
//...
pcm = snd_pcm_writei(handle, buffer_alsa, bframes);
if (pcm < 0)
pcm = snd_pcm_recover(handle, pcm, 0);
if (pcm < 0)
{
std::cout << "              snd_pcm_writei failed:  " <<   snd_strerror(pcm) << std::endl;
return;
}
if (pcm > 0 && pcm < bframes)
{
std::cout << "                   expected / wrote:  " << bframes << " / " << pcm << std::endl;
//return;
}


output:
expected / wrote:  6894888 / 1048576
```

Comment: 1048576 is a suspiciously round number (1MB).  Could it be some sort of buffer overflow, or circular buffer problem?

Comment: Could you hear about Nonblocking Sockets with select? http://read.pudn.com/downloads166/ebook/757380/bluetooth_essentials_for_programmers.4272206415.pdf      page 36

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzab6/xnonblock.htm